# Percona XtraBackup "create" vs "prepare" backup

Tags: backup, database-backups, percona, prepare

I'm trying to understand XtraBackup and I can't really get the difference between **creating** a backup and **preparing** it. Preparing for what? I've created a backup, what for is the preparation? Does it anyway need to be prepared? E.g. [here](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/recipes_ibkx_local.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_option_reference.html to option --apply-log

> -apply-log Prepare a backup in BACKUP-DIR by applying the transaction log file named xtrabackup_logfile located in the same directory. Also,
>   create new transaction logs. The InnoDB configuration is read from the
>   file backup-my.cnf created by innobackupex when the backup was made.
>   innobackupex –apply-log uses InnoDB configuration from backup-my.cnf
>   by default, or from –defaults-file, if specified. InnoDB configuration
>   in this context means server variables that affect data format, i.e.
>   innodb_page_size, innodb_log_block_size, etc. Location-related
>   variables, like innodb_log_group_home_dir or innodb_data_file_path are
>   always ignored by –apply-log, so preparing a backup always works with
>   data files from the backup directory, rather than any external ones.